# Prevent Spot Instances from shutting down when being used by Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently we have configured a set of spot instances, using GPU instance types (g3s.large).

However, even though the instances are being used by Jenkins to build our project, they sometimes get terminated and are assigned another instance to the spot request.

Yesterday, we had 4 canceled builds during that process, just to start again the next one with the new instance. The build time is over half an hour, to it is frustrating to get canceled in the middle of it.

Is it possible to change the configuration, so that the Spot Requests do not get terminated by AWS when having (maybe?) CPU usage?

I do understand that probably having on-demand would be better in this case, but is there a way to keep using Spot Requests?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to stop a spot instance from being killed by AWS when they need the capacity back. That's kind of the whole point of spot instances, you get a pricing discount to use otherwise idle instances, but they take it back whenever someone comes along willing to pay full price for that instance. Have you looked into configuring your spot request to hibernate instead of terminate when they are interrupted?